# Delay in Broadcastreceiver call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

**I am calling BroadcastReceiver on Some Time Input, but I am getting 10-15 seconds delay in onReceive of Broadcast.**

> Activity.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DashboardActivity.this, TimeAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DashboardActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeinMillis, pendingIntent);
```

> TimeAlarm.class

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

    Debug.e("RECEIVER_TIME", "ALARM_READY");
```

Comment: What is `timeinMillis` and what android version are you on?

Comment: timeinMillis is time of Alarm when I calling BroadcastReceiver and in 4.4 & 5.0 of Android and not tested on other versions -  I getting delay.

Answer (score 2):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

If it is really important that there is no delay, use `setExact` for API 19,20 and 21 and use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` for API 23 and 24.